# how to make put / post calls with breeze js

Tags: asp.net-web-api, breeze

how can you do put / post calls instead of using entityManager.saveChanges when using breeze js?

I basically have a readonly entity that is not being tracked but I need to call a service method that will take a parameter or two and will perform some action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a good question!

For now your best bet would be to bypass the Breeze.saveChanges method and simply use Breeze's ajax adapter directly.  Something like this:

```
ajaxImpl = breeze.config.getAdapterInstance("ajax");
ajaxImpl.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.url",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

We do plan to provide a cleaner wrapper for this in one of the next few versions, but we are still trying to come up with the right design.