# BreezeJS saveChanges sends an array instead of an object

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

This question stems off of this other [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18129539/how-to-make-put-post-calls-with-breeze-js).  I'm currently using BreezeJS with Entity Framework but I don't believe I am using it quite the way it was intended.  Currently I am calling save changes on an array of entities that I am sending to the server and then deserializing them into their original structure.  I'm hoping there's a better way to do this that I just haven't been able to find.  There are two ways I see I could do this but can't get them to work.

First would be to send the array over as a single object that when deserialized would already be in the object structure.  When client side that is the format the object is held in so it wouldn't take any additional work.

The second option would be to somehow use the array that is sent to the server and build the object structure using the Entity Framework Metadata within EFContextProvider.

If possible I would prefer a solution closer to option one.

Javascript

```
function saveObjects() {
    // Assume the child class has a foreign key to the parent
    var parent = dataService.createEntity('PARENT', parentObject);
    var child = dataService.createEntity('CHILD', childObject);

    // Save changes
    // This is what I'm currently doing because each entity is seperate
    dataService.saveChanges([parent, child]);
    // This is what I would like to do
    // dataService.saveChanges(parent);
}
```

The object that is currently sent looks like this.  I want CHILD to actually be a child within the PARENT object when it gets sent across.

```
// Current saveBundle
{"entities":  [
    {"ID: 1, 
    "entityAspect": {"entityTypeName": "PARENT", ...}},
    {"PARENT_ID: 1, 
    "entityAspect": {"entityTypeName": "CHILD", ...}}
]}

// Ideal saveBundle
{"entities":  [
    {"ID: 1, 
        {"PARENT_ID: 1, 
        "entityAspect": {"entityTypeName": "CHILD", ...}},
    "entityAspect": {"entityTypeName": "PARENT", ...}},

]}
```

C#

```
[HttpPost]
public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle)
{
    // Currently I have to deserialize each object and rebuild the object
    // because the save bundle is a list of single entities instead of
    // the existing object hierarchy
    PARENT parent = DeserializeEntity(saveBundle, 'PARENT');
    parent.child = DeserializeEntity(saveBundle, 'CHILD');

    // Custom Validation and Saving is done here
}
```

I may be using BreezeJS incorrectly but the validation and database saving happens in separate modules further down the line.  I'm just trying to cut out some the manual work in the middle (having to rebuild the object structure).

Comment: Even when the entities are related on the client, Breeze splits them into an array to avoid circular-reference problems when serializing to JSON.  On the server, the EFContextProvider adds them to an EF context; EF automatically reconstructs the object graph during this process.

Comment: That's the problem, I can't find any examples of how this is done.  On the server I have the array of entities that was sent but I can't figure out how to use my EFContextProvider to build my object from the array.

Comment: But why do you need to do that when it does it for you automatically?

Comment: Because I want to control the save.  Once the data gets to the controller I rebuild the structures and have the data validation within the objects themselves.  Once they have passed validation I submit to the database using EF.  Currently the system works I just want to pull out the manual rebuilding of the data structure if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

One way to address your problem is to perform work in the `BeforeSaveEntities` method.  There, the entities have already been deserialized, but are still not in an object graph.  You can have EF arrange them in an object graph for you by attaching them to a separate Context (not the same one used for saving).

See [this SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36340849/2517406) for more details.